# flutter how to stop confetti lopping

Tags: flutter, dart

I have used confetti package it works but I want to know how to stop lopping the confetti ,
i tried shouldloop = false; but still lopping

```
ConfettiWidget(

          confettiController: Ccontroller,shouldLoop: false,
          blastDirectionality: BlastDirectionality.explosive,
          blastDirection: -pi / 2,
          numberOfParticles: 30,
          gravity: 0.1,

        ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I run your code on the emulator, the confetti animation stops after about 10 seconds and it doesn't loop. If you want to stop it manually after some time, you can call the `stop()` method on `ConfettiController`.

```
() async {
  _confettiController.play();
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
  _confettiController.stop();
}
```